# jQuery UI - Can't drop the first time in hidden area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, user-interface

Here is a fiddle of my problem :
http://jsfiddle.net/p0ulpe/x2r6f9nt/12/

and my JS code :

```
$( ".infos.drag" ).draggable({ 
    revert: 'invalid', 
    helper: "clone",
    connectToSortable: "#appl",
    appendTo: 'body'
});

$('#appl').droppable({
    accept: ".infos",
    activate: function( event, ui ) {
        $('#liste-appli').addClass('active dragging');
    }
}).sortable();
```

I have an hidden area I'm displaying when dragging an element. The first time I drop my element in the area it doesn't drop, but the second time it works.
Can you help me to see what doesn't work the first time ?

Thank you.

Comment: Your problem is `display:none;`.

Comment: You can use `opacity:0;` instead of `display:none;`

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I can't just use opacity to hide the drop area as it will be in a "popup" above the content in absolute position. I tried to hide the area with a left and top position to -9999px but it doesn't work either..

Comment: Can you give me your completed demo to check it?

Comment: I don't have a link to the demo. Finally I append a custom element with the oldest element infos in it when the drop event happen, and it works.